# Angular 5 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API File Upload - Corrupted files

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I am trying to upload a ASP.NET Core Class library file (DLL) from my Angular 5 Client application. On the server side, I have a ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API to receive the uploaded file. I have used the standard recommended mechanism. The client side code is as follows

```
 uploadAssemblyFile(file: File): any {
      const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
      formdata.append('file', file, file.name);
      const endpoint = '/api/upload';
      const req = new HttpRequest('POST', endpoint, formdata, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'json'
      });

      return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

The server side codes is as follows,

```
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("api/upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAssembly(IFormFile file)
    {
        long size = file.Length;
        var uploads = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "uploads");

        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);                        
            }
        }


        return Ok();
    }
```

The Web API is correctly invoked, the IFormFile has all the required details. The file gets saved. However, the file seems to be corrupted. The size of the original file and the uploaded files as seen using the Properties on Windows are different.

The same happens with PNG files. However, TXT files seem to get uploaded correctly.

Has anyone encountered anything similar as above. I have looked at several posts, but haven't got the requisite answer.

Any pointers will certainly help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing the headers of the POST so that there is no context-type: `headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }`

Comment: @cgTag - This doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have the same problem. Found a solution ?